# angular 2 form via method post does not work

Tags: php, forms, angular, post

Hy everyone,
I wish to create an angular 2 web form that sends data to a php server file via method post. i want the form to have all angular 2 capabilities such as validators and nice animation functions combined with the ability to send the user data to the server via method post. the combination does not work. while angular2 validators and animation works when filling out the form and clicking submit, the data is not sent to the php server file. this is despite different regular simple html form does send the data via method post successfully.

Here is the code:
 form [formGroup]="myForm" action="http://www.delikates.co.il/backend/addUser" method="post"
...... form
where is the mistake ?

Thanx, Daniel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys i solved it: i missed some simple code inside the form element:

Comment: Please elaborate what was missing, and also elaborate the code in your question. This post is not of any use to anyone else without this crucial data ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use http to achieve what you  want

```
return this.http.post(this.yourUrl, body, options)
   request.map(
     (res:Response) => res.json())
  .catch(
    (error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

This will return a Observable that you can subscribe to.